# How do I test gestures on desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, desktop

I am using the library quo js and I was wondering how am I supposed to test web gestures while coding on my desktop. Is there a way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use eclipse to run an [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html). It works, but I'd rather test it with an actual mobile device if you can, as the emulator is horribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Get a canary build of Google Chrome, under developer settings there is an option 'Emulate touch events'.

For Firefox you'll have to rely on a third party plugin like [Touch enabler](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/touch-enabler/).